# how can I change the color of Toast depends on message type in Angular material $mdToast?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, toast, angular-material

While using `$mdToast.simple().content("some test")` it is showing the toast with black color. how can I change that color to red, yellow and so, depends on the type of the error messages like error, warning and success.

Similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614767/how-to-show-md-toast-with-background-color).

Comment: You should change the toast text color, not the background color. Changing the background color goes against the Material Design spec. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage

Comment: Update: Changing the background color goes against the Material Design spec. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage If you are using a snackbar as opposed to a toast, then you can change the color of the action button text. If you need to display an error that the user must see and take action on, then a toast or snackbar is the wrong component to use.

Comment: We use a different color for toast and it looks great. Nothing wrong with tweaking Material Design to suit your needs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT:**
For a correct implementation, please use [rlay3s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403314/rlay3) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993606/2552918) below :)!

**OUTDATED:**
I had problems displaying custom text with jhblacklocks solution, so I decided to do it like this using 'template':

```
var displayToast = function(type, msg) {

    $mdToast.show({
        template: '<md-toast class="md-toast ' + type +'">' + msg + '</md-toast>',
        hideDelay: 6000,
        position: 'bottom right'
    });
};
```

I also added the different types in my .css file:

```
.md-toast.error {
    background-color: red;
}

.md-toast.success {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Don't know if this is the most beautiful approach, but I don't need a template files for each dialog type and displaying custom text is really easy.

Comment: This doesn't follow the Material Design Guidelines... You can see on this link (https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/toast/toast-theme.scss) that the background is always fixed. See my answer to see how you can theme it correctly.

Comment: Note that you need to escape any user data in `msg`, or you'll have an XSS issue.

Comment: This is not only incorrect but also breaks the material ui rendering for md-toast.....Answer by [rlay3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30993606/598420) is correct!

Answer (score 85):

There is an easier way by specifying a theme:

```
$mdToast.simple().content("some test").theme("success-toast")
```

And in your CSS:

```
md-toast.md-success-toast-theme {
    background-color: green;
    ...
}
```

You could incorporate your message type to dynamically select a theme.

**Update**:
As Charlie Ng pointed out, to avoid warnings regarding use of an unregistered custom theme register it in your module using the theme provider: `$mdThemingProvider.theme("success-toast")`

**Another update**:
There was a [breaking change](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/cae51a65f883595cb73fed4dba9e60c7c068facc) created on 2 Dec 2015 (v1.0.0+). You now need to specify:

```
md-toast.md-success-toast-theme {
    .md-toast-content {
        background-color: green;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Like has been noted in other comments, this does not follow the Material Design spec: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage

Comment: They're called Material Design **Guide**lines. The page also says "Default background fill", implying that there is room for non-default fills.

Comment: I liked this solution better because it added a target-able class without messing with the template. Agreed that ultimate solution would be to use the theme provider.

Answer (score 13):

register themes:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme("success-toast");
$mdThemingProvider.theme("error-toast");
```

add css:

```
md-toast.md-error-toast-theme div.md-toast-content{
    color: white !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}

md-toast.md-success-toast-theme div.md-toast-content{
    color: white !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

use:

```
$mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
        .content(message)
        .hideDelay(2000)
        .position('bottom right')
        .theme(type + "-toast")
);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can see on this link that you cannot change the background color of the element, it'll be always fixed:

https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/toast/toast-theme.scss

This is because the Material Design Guidelines for Toasts states that the background will always remains the same:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-specs

Note the `background` item on the *Specs* list.

Nothing is said about the text color in each situation, it's implied that it follows the `backgroundPalette`, on the '50' hue rotation, declared on that CSS on the GitHub Link.

The way to distinct a `warn` toast, or an `accent`-ted one, from the default, calling an `action toast`, each with its action button using the appropriate class (`md-warn` or `md-accent`).

```
$mdToast.show({
    template: '<md-toast>\
        {{ toast.content }}\
        <md-button ng-click="toast.resolve()" class="md-warn">\
            Ok\
        </md-button>\
    </md-toast>',
    controller: [function () {
        this.content = 'Toast Content';
    }],
    controllerAs: 'toast'
});
```

The toast itself, which its `default` form means an action report, with success implied. If it needs more even more attention, <strike>force its close by setting up an action button</strike> add actions like 'Retry', 'Report a problem', 'Details', which can be used to catch this click and record some technical info, etc... the examples vary from what you need.

Comment: This is a great answer because it takes into account the actual material visual language. I needed to draw attention to an "error" toast and this was perfect -- in my case, the warning-themed button is labeled "details" and shows the user additional (possibly technical) information about a malfunction. If I had made the background red, which was my kneejerk impulse, it would have looked like tacky bootstrap stuff.

Comment: This should be the right answer because it follows MD's well documented design specs, while the question does not...

Comment: Note that currently this won't work as there's CSS for `md-toast .md-toast-content .md-button` that'll override the button's color. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6256

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the order of those CSS rules appended on runtime need to be fixed. Minor problem, if we accept that the guidelines are mandatory over the development of angular-material.

Comment: Using a button to dismiss the toast is against the Material Design spec, see "0-1 actions, not dismiss or cancel" in the spec here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage If you have another action like 'Details' or 'Retry' then that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

One more step to rlay3's answer.

Angular Material at 0.7.1 added warning to unregistered themes.
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#071--2015-01-30

If theme is not registered, every time the toast shows up, you will be getting a warning message in console like, for example:

```
attempted to use unregistered theme 'custom-toast'
angular.js:12416 Attempted to use unregistered theme 'custom-toast'. 
Register it with $mdThemingProvider.theme().
```

To get rid of the warning, you will need to configure the theme 'custom-toast' in your angular app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom-toast')
});
```

and use it like:

```
$mdToast.simple().content("some test").theme("custom-toast");
```

references: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/04_multiple_themes

Comment: The `.config(...` part was exactly what I was missing. Only when I added that, my toast started working correctly :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You did ask about using the simple toast call.  Would you mind trying a custom toast show [like the demo](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.toast) and add classes to the template?

JS

```
$mdToast.show(
  controller: 'ToastCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/shared/toast.html',
  hideDelay: 6000,
  position: $scope.getToastPosition()
)
```

TEMPLATE

```
<md-toast class="flash">
  <span flex>Custom toast!</span>
  <md-button ng-click="closeToast()">
   Close
  </md-button>
</md-toast>
```

CSS

```
md-toast.flash {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

CONTROLLER (COFFEE)

```
'use strict'

###*
 # @ngdoc function
 # @name angularApp.controller:ToastCtrl
 # @description
 # # ToastCtrl
 # Controller of the angularApp
###
angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller 'ToastCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.closeToast = ()->
      $mdToast.hide()
```

Comment: Using a button to close the toast is against the Material Design spec, see "0-1 actions, not dismiss or cancel" in the spec here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage If you have another action like 'Details' or 'Retry' then that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another option, `$mdToast` allows to define toast *presets* that you can easily instantiate in this way, though i'm struggling to understand how to change the text content, any idea?

```
$mdToast.show(
  $mdToast.error()
);
```

The *presets* are defined as explained on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast :

```
$mdToastProvider.addPreset('error', {
  options: function() {
    return {
      template:
        '<md-toast>' +
          '<div class="md-toast-content">' +
          '</div>' +
        '</md-toast>',
      position: 'top left',
      hideDelay: 2000,
      toastClass: 'toast-error',
      controllerAs: 'toast',
      bindToController: true
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I first favoured the solution but I don't like setting up a theme in the theme provider just for a toast. So how about this solution:

JS (Coffee)

```
   if error
      message = ''

      if error.reason is 'Incorrect password'
        message = 'Email and password combination is incorrect'
      if error.reason is 'User not found'
        message = 'No account found with this email address'

      $mdToast.show(
        templateUrl:  'client/modules/toasts/toastError.html'
        hideDelay:    3000
        controller: ( $scope ) ->
          $scope.message    =  message
          $scope.class      = 'error'
          $scope.buttonLabel = 'close'
          $scope.closeToast = ->
            $mdToast.hide()
      ).then( ( result ) ->
        if result is 'ok'
          console.log('do action')
      )
```

and then HTML (JADE)

```
md-toast(ng-class="class")
  span(flex) {{message}}
  md-button.md-action(ng-click="closeToast()") {{buttonLabel}}
```

I tried to use the `locals` option to pass variables to the controller, but for some reason they are not injected.(https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.toast/service/$mdToast check list of options under `show` function)

Then last the CSS (STYLUS)

```
md-toast.success
  background-color    green

md-toast.error
  background-color    red
```

Summary: there is on template in this case which you can give custom placeholders which you prefill in your controller.
This solution works for me.

Comment: Using a button to close the toast is against the Material Design spec, see "0-1 actions, not dismiss or cancel" in the spec here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage If you have another action like 'Details' or 'Retry' then that would be appropriate. Additionally, coloring the text of the toast is in the spec, but coloring the background is not.

Comment: They close their toast themselves only they call it OK: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast (check custom toast). How you color your toast in your own project is up to you, not Google. They just set out the spec but if you want to give a toast a danger color it is up to you IMO

Comment: Good point! I've opened an issue for that: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6607

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with factory and some css.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('ToastService', ToastService);

  /** @ngInject */
  function ToastService($mdToast) {

    var service = {
      error: error,
      success: success,
      info : info
    };

    return service;

    //////////

    function success(text) {
      $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
          .toastClass("toast-success")
          .textContent(text)
      );
    }

    function info(text) {
      $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
          .toastClass("toast-info")
          .textContent(text)
      );
    }

    function error(text) {
      $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
          .toastClass("toast-error")
          .textContent(text)
      );
    }
  }
}());
```

And css.

```
.toast-error .md-toast-content{
  background-color: rgb(102,187,106) !important;
}

.toast-info .md-toast-content{
  background-color: rgb(41,182,246) !important;
}

.toast-error .md-toast-content{
  background-color: rgb(239,83,80) !important;
}
```