# How to show md-toast with background color

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to create md-toast with having some background color to toast using angular-material. I using answers from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481029/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-toast-depends-on-message-type-in-angular-material), I created this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjWNWd), but it is showing some unwanted background to toast as well.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout-fill="" layout="column" class="inset toastdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <p>
    Toast is not properly working with theme defined in CSS.
    <br>
  </p>

  <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-around">
    <md-button ng-click="showSimpleToast()">
      Toast
    </md-button>
  </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
md-toast.md-success-toast-theme {
    background-color: green;
}

md-toast.md-error-toast-theme {
    background-color: maroon;
    position: 'top right'
}

md-toast {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    top:10px;
}
```

JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdToast, $document) {
  $scope.showSimpleToast = function() {
    $mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.simple()
        .textContent('Simple lala Toast!')
      .theme('success-toast')
        .hideDelay(3000)
    );
  };
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Positioning the toast

Instead of giving a position to everything (which makes the cutting of your toast), you can position only the `md-toast` to the right position.

By the documentation, there are four location where you can officially put the toast: **top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right**. So, first, lets position the toast to **top left** (this is important for the change in animation. Also, this will allow us to show toasts on **bottom center** as well).

```
$mdToast.show(
  $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent('Simple lala Toast!')
    .position('top')
```

now, in the css, just position your toast:

```
md-toast {
  left: calc(50vw - 150px);
}
```

This will position the toast at the center of the **viewport**, minus half of the toast.

you can also show toasts on the bottom center by javascript alone:

```
$mdToast.show(
  $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent('Simple lala Toast!')
    .position('bottom')
```

and the toast will center at the bottom and use the right animation to show it.

## Coloring the toast

You colored the toast's container instead of the actual content of the toast. To color the toast, you can add the following css styling:

```
md-toast.md-success-toast-theme .md-toast-content {
  background-color: green;
}
```

You can change the toast's theme to not override the default toast styling. Also, changing the position for a specific theme can help use both positions (default and manual) at the same time (by changing theme).

```
md-toast.md-thatkookooguy-toast-theme {
  left: calc(50vw - 150px);
}
```

Here's a working [FORK](http://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/jWBqve) of you codepen.

Comment: This will also allow you to keep using `.position('top left')` and `.position('bottom left')`. If you want to keep the right styles instead, you can change the **css positioning** to `right: calc(50vw - 150px);`

Comment: when I use .theme(..) a warning always is shown in the Javascript console

Answer (score 7):

> `.toastClass(string)` Sets a class on the toast element

Define css:

```
.md-toast-done .md-toast-content{
    background: #004f75 !important;
}

.md-toast-error .md-toast-content{
    background: rgb(193, 30, 23) !important;
}
```

And define toast:

```
    $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
            .toastClass('md-toast-error')
            .textContent(stringValue)
            .position('bottom right')
            .hideDelay(3000)
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

When using

```
$mdToast.simple().theme('sometheme');
```

A warning occurs in the console that the specified theme has not been defined. Better is to use the toastClass attribute.

```
var message = "An error occured!";
$mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({
  hideDelay: 126000,
  position: 'top right',
  content: message,
  toastClass: 'error'
}));
```

SCSS:

```
$red: rgb(244, 67, 54);
$green: rgb(76, 175, 80);

md-toast {
  &.error {
    .md-toast-content {
      background: $red;
      color: white;
    }
  }
  &.success {
    .md-toast-content {
      background: $green;
      color: white;
    }
  }
}
```

Working example [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ninox92/pen/jAgjAr)

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? This looks like a viable solution to me for those who'd rather not get into the world of theming.

Comment: This seems to be the "official" way as discussed in that thread: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2878