# How to change text color of Toast message using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

self.showToast('Only two studies at a time is allowed to compare','warning');

Comment: refer here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481029/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-toast-depends-on-message-type-in-angular-material